# Select values from a select

Tags: sql

I've made a simple select statement that takes every 'depth' where 'priority' = 1.

```
select HOLEID, DEPTH, SURVTYPE from HOLESURVEY WHERE PRIORITY = 1
```

I want to filter the result so that it shows me all HOLEID where there is more than 1 same depth for the same HOLEID.

Can someone helps me with taht?

Comment: What's the database? Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase, etc.

Comment: You need a SubQuery/CTE

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Please show sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
with 
x as (
  select HOLEID, DEPTH, SURVTYPE from HOLESURVEY WHERE PRIORITY = 1
)
select *
from x
where (HOLEID, DEPTH) in (
  select HOLEID, DEPTH
  from x
  group by HOLEID, DEPTH
  having count(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `group by HOLEID` to get all the ids that apply to your conditions:

```
SELECT * FROM HOLESURVEY
WHERE HOLEID IN (
  SELECT HOLEID
  FROM HOLESURVEY 
  WHERE PRIORITY = 1
  GROUP BY HOLEID
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DEPTH) < COUNT(DEPTH)
)
```

If you only need HOLEIDs:

```
SELECT HOLEID
FROM HOLESURVEY 
WHERE PRIORITY = 1
GROUP BY HOLEID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DEPTH) < COUNT(DEPTH)
```

Comment: Looking at the question, it seems that she doesn't need the other columns. Just `HOLEID`. As such, my interpretation is that your inner query would already suffice. Nice of you to add a way to get the other columns, though. +1

Comment: Maybe, but this: *I want to filter the result so that it shows me all HOLEID...* could mean filter the results of the 1st query. Anyway I will include it in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's a bit ambiguous, I guess. Anyway, you already have my upvote :D

Comment: I dont't get your constraint onDEPTH. Having 2 records with the same DEPTH for one HOLEID would return true (1 < 2). isn't it simply count(distinct DEPTH) > 1? Your constraint means afaik: At least one DEPTH appaers twice or more

Comment: Each HOLEID can have miltiple different DEPTHS. Suppose there are only 2 DEPTHs: DEPTH1 and DEPTH2 each appearing only once. This will return 2 for `count(distinct DEPTH)`, right? But you don't want this HOLEID in the results because both DEPTHs appear only once.

Comment: Your rIght, I read the question like 'more the one different DEPTH'

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation.  I think you want:

```
select HOLEID, DEPTH
from HOLESURVEY 
where PRIORITY = 1
group by HOLEID, DEPTH
having COUNT(*) > 1;
```

You can include `COUNT(*)` in the `SELECT` to show how many depths match for a given hole.

Answer (score 0):

As I suppose you need such records which are having same holeid and same depth multiple number of times.

```
    select HOLEID, DEPTH, count(*) recCounter from HOLESURVEY 
            group by HOLEID, DEPTH having count(*) > 1
```

and if need detail rows then

```
    SELECT * FROM HOLESURVEY a 
    inner join 
        (select HOLEID, DEPTH from HOLESURVEY 
            group by HOLEID, DEPTH having count(*) > 1) b
    on b.holeid = a.holeid and b.depth = a.depth
```